# images as background for retina display in ie7+8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background, retina-display

good morning everybody,

my problem today is, that I would like to use some background-images for mobile phones (retina and non-retina), also for desktop browsers (like the actuell version of google chrome, firefox, internet explorer).

my css, or how I use it:
.item { background-image: url(../images/list-background.png); background-size:24px 24px; }

the original list-background.png is (for retina devices) 48*48* pixel width/height.
in all browsers, there is no problem with the css3 attribute background-size.

now my problem is to support internet explorer 7 and 8.
is there still a useful solution for fixing the background-size in ie7+8?

Answer (score 0):

css3pie offers support for non-repeating background images background-size declaration for ie6 and ie7. http://css3pie.com/2013/01/28/pie-2-0-beta-1-released/ there's also a polyfill that supports ie8. https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

or you could simply use conditional comments in your media queries to serve up separate separate images to ie7 and ie8.

Comment: okey, now i use css3pie, but, how should this work:.item { background-image: url(../images/list-20x42.png);background-size: 10px 21px;behavior: url(css/PIE.htc); } ? thanks a lot.

Comment: follow the instructions. i've never used it, but it should be pretty straight forward. also, accept this answer if it works for you